# I want to authenticate Twitter using Socialite on Laravel8, but it works locally, but I get an error on Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, twitter, twitter-oauth, laravel-8

I want to implement Twitter authentication in Laravel 8.
I am using Socialite.
The local operation check was successful.
I authenticated with Twitter and was able to get the name.
When I deploy to Heroku, I get an error.
The environment variables for Heroku (TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_REDIRECT_URI, TWITTER_SECRET) are set.

```
heroku run composer show -i
```

laravel / socialite and socialiteproviders/twitter and socialiteproviders/manager has been uploaded to heroku.

[Status]
Error when starting Twitter authentication from Laravel8 application.

```
League\OAuth1\Client\Signature\HmacSha1Signature::League\OAuth1\Client\Signature\{closure}(): Argument #2 ($value) must be passed by reference, value given
```

[Environment]
Heroku
Laravel8
Socilite

I'm not good at English, but I'll do my best. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been solved here: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth1-client/issues/127
I asked for a new release. So you either wait for the new release, or you (temporarily) require the latest dev version which includes the bugfix via:

```
composer require league/oauth1-client:dev-master
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Thank you! ありがとうございます！

Answer (score -1):

I just want to share another solution I came up with. Because the error only occurred on PHP 8, you could also just change your composer requirement to not use PHP 8 (if you have no requirement that depends on that version).

To change it, you could edit your composer.json file and change this line:

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
```

to this:

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
```

then run `composer update`. hope it could be useful for other people encounter this problem

Comment: Literally downgrading PHP isn't really a proper solution IMO.